# xamarin forms master detail page with dynamic menu list

Tags: xaml, navigation-drawer, xamarin.forms

I need the menu items on the master page to change dynamically, i.e. different menu items on master page on different detail pages ? How can we achieve this .

Say on login page I have two menu items , after login I get a master page with four menu items.

Comment: please post the code you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean listing the items with different template you can use `ListView` with [`TemplateSelector`](https://blog.xamarin.com/customizing-list-view-cells-xamarin-forms-datatemplateselector/). If you want to use different page template you can use `ContentPage` or `TemplatedPage` for both `Master` and `Detail` side with setting te property [`ControlTemplate`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/templates/control-templates/creating/)